# Transforming time series of different time horizon to stationary

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration

I have a list of monthly time series data with different time periods and different order of integration. I want to transform them all to stationary and a same time period. 
I noticed that the order of integration of a time series could be different with different number of data points. For example:

- TS$_1$ is I(1) with 67 obs.
- TS$_2$ is I(1) with 108 obs., I(2) with 67 obs., I(1) with 66 obs., and I(2) with 65 obs.
- TS$_3$ is I(1) with 108 obs., I(0) with 67 obs., and I(1) with 66 obs., etc.

Suppose my data start at different times, but end at the same date.
What is the best practice to transform them to stationary?
Thank you!